# IntelliJ java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\User\...\java_bridge.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, maven, windows-7, intellij-idea, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to import a IntelliJ java web application project (Maven Project) from a linux system to a Windows system. This java program relies on 2 external libraries to run.

On the linux system both libraries load fine when I run my test cases (and pass successful), however when I moved over to the windows system, 1 of the libraries no longer works properly (and yes i did make sure to get the approproaite windows binaries).

I keep getting the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SAINT\Packages\cellml-sdk-1.9\lib\cellml_java_bridge.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

At this point I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, because the .dll is present in the directory.
The location of the .dll is also present in the windows PATH variable, and I have specified to java using -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SAINT\Packages\cellml-sdk-1.9\lib

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look in the eventlog for windows side by side (SxS) messages.  They will likely point to the missing dll.  If not, use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: Ok, so I've run D.Walker, and it gives me 3 missing dependencies. I've added the location of these dll's to PATH, but dependency walker still tells me it cant find them. Any suggestions?

Comment: ah, DW is hard to use.  You have to poke around it to try to figure out what is going on.  Evenlog usually is the easier option.  If that doesn't work, you can also try Process Monitor from sysinternals, it will show you java trying to look for DLLs in PATH and getting file not found errors.

Comment: Ok there's lots of stuff, I kind of filtered it down to the times when i ran the failed tests. what kind of message am I looking for?

Comment: Stop java. Filter just on your process, (java.exe).  Filter to only show file access (ignore network, registry, process).   STart your test process.  This should be manageable, like under 1000 entries.  Look for access to your failing dll.  Right after java.exe reads your dll it will try reading dlls that it depends on and will fail to find them.

Comment: ok in process monitor, i found where cellml_java_bridge.dll first appears, and as you said it would stop at various dlls. I added the location of each dll to the path individually, the last one loaded was msvcr80.dll, all dlls appear to be successfully found by java, although im not entirely sure how to distinguish whether it was successful or not. Then it just loops back to 'Read File' C:\Users\...\cellml_java_bridge.dll (repeats 4 times) and then "close file". Finally it runs 'thread exit'--> then it seems to go about tidying up the tests still fail in IntelliJ.

Comment: oh ok wait my error message has changed to

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SAINT\Packages\cellml-sdk-1.9\lib\cellml_java_bridge.dll: The specified procedure could not be found

Comment: well...that sucks. Apparently - Quote: "the DLL does not contain the native method [I'm] trying to call in with the name, format etc. that Java expects it to be...". I'm not really sure how to fix that...

Comment: if it is failing to load msvcr80.dll likely you can't fix it by playing with your path variable.  It gets into side by side windows dll crap which I do not fully understand.  Try installing VC runtime redistributable packages.

Comment: Awesome. Got it to work in the end. I appreciate all the help. As it turns out, I was using a fairly outdated API, updating to a more recent version and repeating your steps fixed the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says: Can't find *dependent* libraries. The DLL you have needs other DLLs, and they need to be in a directory located in the PATH environment variable, not java.library.path.

To see what the dependencies are, you can use objdump.

You haven't been adding full paths to .dll files to PATH, have you? Just put the directories containing the dependents into path.

Comment: is there a way I can find out which dll's are required and where they should be. When I did this on linux it was much simpler ...